# tikz matrix : centering cells

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, matrices

I have what's below and I do not know why the term m_{n+1,k} is not horizontally centered in its cell?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current  bounding  box.center)]
\tikzset{square matrix/.style={outer sep=-6pt,matrix of nodes,
nodes={draw,
minimum height=0.7cm,
anchor=center,
text width=0.7cm,
align=center,
outer sep=-6pt}}}
\matrix(mymatrix)[square matrix,left delimiter={[},right delimiter={]}]{
1 & 0\\
0 & $-m_{n+1,k}$\\};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Because you specified `text width`, so the cell can't become large enough to accommodate the whole text. Try `minimum width` instead. Side question: Do you actually want the node borders to be drawn, or is this just for testing purposes?

Comment: borders are here for testing purposes. I'll give the minimum width option a try. Thank you

Comment: Just remove the `text width=0.7cm` and it will center automatically anyway or reduce the font size with `\scriptscriptstyle`. Otherwise you will be overprinting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, the minimum width option helps but I am now using a `\makebox[0pt][c]{$-m_{k+1,n}$}` to get the desired matrix.